# Amazon EC2 & S3 When using Python / SQLite?

Tags: python, sqlite, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Suppose that I have a huge `SQLite` file (say, 500[MB]) stored in Amazon `S3`. 
Can a `python` script that is run on a small `EC2` instance **directly access and modify** that `SQLite` file? or must I first copy the file to the `EC2` instance, change it there and then copy over to `S3`?

Will the I/O be efficient?

Here's what I am trying to do. As I wrote, I have a 500[MB] `SQLite` file in `S3`. I'd like to start say `10 different Amazon EC2 instances` that will each read a subset of the file and do some processing (every instance will handle a different subset of the 500[MB] `SQLite` file). Then, once processing is done, every instance will update only the subset of the data it dealt with (as explained, there will be *no overlap of data* among processes).

For example, suppose that the `SQLite` file has say **1M rows**:

`instance 1` will deal with (and update) rows `0 - 100000`

`instance 2` will will deal with (and update) rows `100001 - 200000`

.........................

`instance 10` will deal with (and update) rows `900001 - 1000000`

---

Is it at all possible? Does it sound OK? any suggestions / ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'd like to start say 10 different Amazon EC2 instances that will each read a subset of the file and do some processing (every instance will handle a different subset of the 500[MB] SQLite file)

You cannot do this with SQLite; on amazon infrastructure or otherwise.  sqlite performs database level write locking.  unless all ten nodes are performing reads exclusively, you will not attain any kind of concurrency.  [Even the SQLite website says so.](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html)

> Situations Where Another RDBMS May Work Better
>
> - Client/Server Applications
> - High-volume Websites
> - Very large datasets
> - High Concurrency

Have you considered PostgreSQL?

Comment: I suspect that the OP is looking to scale out due to the processing requirements, rather than the DB concurrency. If that is the case then locking the DB will(may?) not be an issue.

Comment: Even so, SQLite tends to abort transactions if it feels they may be concurrent.  The only way to do this would be to use a mutex lock (something that is outside the scope of SQLite) to obtain the database for a write.  Really any RDBMS other than SQLite is likely to be more practical/convenient.

Comment: Guys, thank you. The thing is, after my processing is over, I'd like to send over the results (= the `SQLite` file). While `MySQL` or so can help to store the results on Amazon's end -- how will I retrieve the results back to my computer?

Comment: @user3262424: native database binary formats are undesirable.  You should prefer interchange formats that are easy to convert from one application to another.  The gold standard in database interchange is CSV.  You can do that easily with mysqldump http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-backup-excerpt/5.5/en/mysqldump-delimited-text.html

Answer (score 2):

Since S3 cannot be directly mounted, your best bet is to create an EBS volume containing the SQLite file and work directly with the EBS volume from another (controller) instance.  You can then create snapshots of the volume, and archive it into S3.  Using a tool like boto (Python API), you can automate the creation of snapshots and the process of moving the backups into S3.

Comment: Beringer: Thank you. So let me make sure I understand: can the `EBS Volume` be accessed (and its contents modified / updated) from all 10 instances **at the same time**?

Comment: If it is attached to an instance, you can use nfs to make it available to the other instances.

Answer (score 2):

You can mount S3 bucket on your linux machine. See below:

> s3fs -
>   http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/InstallationNotes
>   - this did work for me. It uses FUSE file-system + rsync to sync the files
>   in S3. It kepes a copy of all
>   filenames in the local system & make
>   it look like a FILE/FOLDER.

This is good if the system is already in place and running with huge collection of data. But, if you are building this from scratch then I would suggest you to have an EBS volume for SQLite and use this script to create a snapshot of your EBS volume:

> https://github.com/rakesh-sankar/Tools/blob/master/AmazonAWS/EBS/ebs-snapshot.sh

Comment: thank you. The only this is, I read somewhere that an `EBS Volume` can only be mounted to one instance, while I want to have a volume that is shared among all `10 instances`. How do I go about it?

Comment: I doubt you can do that, Amazon EBS can not be shared among different EC2 instances. But you can use Amazon S3 bucket, use it as a drive and share it with any number of EC2 instances you want.

Comment: thank you. So, from your comment, it looks like mounting `S3` bucket is the only way to share data across different `EC2` instances (meaning, an `EBS` volume will not help in this case). Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you can not share EBS volume on different EC2 machines, but S3 bucket.

Comment: Great, this clarifies things.

Answer (score 2):

If your db structure is simple, why not just use [AWS simpledb](http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/)? Or run mysql (or another DB) on one of your instances.

Comment: To add to this, If you are concerned about the difficulty of managing a DBMS, Amazon offers a hosted MySQL service, called RDS, which is quite simple to use.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: thank you. The thing is, after my processing is over, I'd like to send over the results (= the SQLite file). While `MySQL` or so can help to store the results on Amazon's end -- how will I retrieve the results back to my computer?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon EFS can be shared among ec2 instances. It's a managed NFS share. SQLITE will still lock the whole DB on write.

The SQLITE Website does not recommend NFS shares, though. But depending on the application you can share the DB read-only among several ec2  instances and store the results of your processing somewhere else, then concatenate the results in the next step.